# NGINX proxy_pass returning 502 but the server is logging 200

Tags: nginx, routing, proxy, proxypass

I am attempting to add `location /us/castle/knights` to this nginx server and replace the existing server request at the same url.

When I hit https://localhost/us/castle/knights I get a 502 but I can see the request on http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights responding with 200.

Why am I getting a 502 and how can I fix this so that the request hits the proxy server?

```
error_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/error.log;
pid /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx.pid;
worker_processes  1;
daemon off;
events { worker_connections  1024; }
http {
    access_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/access.log;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        root /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
        location /us/api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
        location /us/castle/knights {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights/;
        }
        location /us/castle {
            alias /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
            index index.dev.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.dev.htm =404;
            autoindex on;
            expires 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide access and error log?

Comment: And are you accessing http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights from same instance as nginx reverse proxy?